# Python: .send function of socket programming

Tags: python, sockets

I send some message 'hello' from client to server using this command on server

```
    #Send some data to remote server
    message = 'hello'

    try :

    s.send(message)
    print 'data sent successfully'
    except socket.error:
    #Send failed
    print 'Send failed'
```

Now on server side , I want to check whether this message is present as a key in dictionary which is created on server side.

```
    msg=c.recvfrom(1024)

     if msg in data2.keys():
 print("key for this msg exists", msg)
     else:
     print("no such key exists",msg)
```

Now, the problem is it always says no such key exits. When I print the msg on server side which I have got from client.It comes out to be:

```
   ('hello', None)
```

I don't get it why it gives None along with hello.

because of this I am not even getting a match in dictionary. Please tell me where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html) for `socket.recvfrom()` you will see that it returns a tuple.  If you only want the data portion, you're better off just calling `socket.recv()`.

Answer (score 2):

As the documentation for socket states: *The return value is a pair (string, address) where string is a string representing the data received and address is the address of the socket sending the data.*

So your `('hello', None)` is this pair and if you want to pick the message string from it to search it in your dict, you have to use `msg[0]`.